How to Pass a Literal ${HOSTNAME} in Docker Compose Environment Variable without evaluation?
I'm working on a Docker Compose setup where I need to pass an environment variable with a literal ${HOSTNAME} format to my application, without Docker Compose attempting to resolve it as an environment variable.
Here’s the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  webapp:
    image: webapp-image
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: webapp/Dockerfile
      target: base
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=$${HOSTNAME} # <-- escape dollar sign with double dollar
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -X GET http://localhost:3000
      start_period: 1m
      start_interval: 5s
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

The result I would obtain is:
services:
      webapp:
        image: webapp-image
        build:
          context: ..
          dockerfile: webapp/Dockerfile
          target: base
        environment:
          - REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME} # <-- single dollar
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
        restart: on-failure
        healthcheck:
          test: curl -X GET http://localhost:3000
          start_period: 1m
          start_interval: 5s
          interval: 20s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 3

However, doing
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml config -o ./docker-compose-final.yml 

in the docker-compose-final.yml I get
...
    - REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=$${HOSTNAME} # <-- still double dollar
...

instead of
...
    - REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME} # <-- single dollar sign
...

Tried also with single quotas but it changes anything.
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

I made a minimal example, I hope I understood your question correctly.
services:
  exampleapp:
    image: alpine
    tty: true
    environment:
      - EXAMPLE_ENV=$${RETAIN_THIS}

Starting the container up with docker compose up -d and then enterin it yields the variable with the dollar sign.
$ docker compose up -d
$ docker exec -it test-exampleapp-1 /bin/sh
$ echo $EXAMPLE_ENV // <- in the container
> ${RETAIN_THIS}

The value of the environment variable includes the special characters.

Hi Philipp, thank you for your answer.
Actually the code you posted works correctly. The fact is that when I run  docker compose -f docker-compose.yml config -o docker-compose-out.yml the content of docker-compose-out.yml is
EXAMPLE_ENV: $${RETAIN_THIS}
is there a way to get the variable without the double dollar?

Hi @gravagnani please update your question with those details, otherwise it is very hard to understand what issue you. have. Nevertheless I ran docker compose -f docker-compose.yml config -o docker-compose-out.yml and in my case docker complains that your input compose file is incorrect: service "webapp" depends on undefined service "api-gateway": invalid compose project.

Hi @os11k, thanks for your suggestion. Actually my code is a snipped of a bigger compose file, so the error about the "api-gateway" (removed the "depens on" property on compose file). In order to understand better the issue, you can try the simpler code of Philipp, it behaves in the same way

Hi @gravagnani so why you need single dollar sign in docker-compose-final.yml? In my understanding it just validates a file and if input file have 2 dollar signs, why you think output file should be with one dollar sign?

Hi @os11k, I need to export the docker compose with the variable literally REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME} in order to set the value of REACT_APP_HOSTNAME at runtime with environment variable. Actually, I need some variables be interpolated at build time (and of course it works), and REACT_APP_HOSTNAME be interpolated at runtime (and to achieve this, I need to set the variable in the docker compose as REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME}).

Hi @gravagnani I didn't understand anything what you wrote, sorry. In container when you run echo $REACT_APP_HOSTNAME. What output should be? Should it be ${HOSTNAME}?

Hi @os11k when I start the container, I set the environment variable HOSTNAME (with .env file). the echo $REACT_APP_HOSTNAME should give the value of the variable HOSTNAME

Hi @gravagnani Do you have a sample code with env var file so I can test, what is wrong with it?

Hi @gravagnani ! could you please answer why you need at all to run docker compose -f docker-compose.yml config -o ./docker-compose-final.yml command? What is the point??? If you create .env file and set variable HOSTNAME there as it should and if you use in your docker compose file ${HOSTNAME} -- with just one dollar sign, I don't even understand why you decided that you need 2, then after docker compose up, you will get REACT_APP_HOSTNAME variable in container as it set in .env file
